# Can't convert String to Integer

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am a beginner. I know this is basic. In my project I am using Java and MySQL workbench. I am reading a data from user by using select box which is coming from database by using ajax.
The code for select box is mentioned below

```
<%
 String a =request.getParameter("course");
 if(a!=null)
   {
       ResultSet rs=s.selectsub(a);
       String Query="select * from  subject where course_id='"+a+"'";
 %>
 <select name="subject" id="subject">
   <option>Select Subject</option>
   <%
    while(rs.next())
    {
    %>
    <option value="<% out.println(rs.getString("subject_id")); %>">
    <% out.println(rs.getString("subject")); %></option>
   <% } %>
  </select>
<%
}
%>
```

and the subject id is passed to another page using post method and trying this code

```
     String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
     int subjectid=Integer.parseInt(subject);
```

But the line Integer conversion is not working. Error is showing. The error is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /saveuser.jsp at line 29
26:          String email=request.getParameter("email");
27:          String designation=request.getParameter("designation");
28:          String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
29:          int subjectid=Integer.parseInt(subject);
30:          String institute=request.getParameter("institute");
31:          String inemail=request.getParameter("inemail");
32:          String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
```

Comment: Advice.. Avoid using scriptlets and instead use JSTL

Comment: r u sure request.getParameter("subject"); or String[] subjects= request.getParameterValues("subject"); ?

Comment: plz go through MVC architecture

Comment: ya i got the answer is was the lack of trim function.

Comment: @gjman2 Because of one issue OP can't change the whole project structure.Yes recommendings are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` method will convert a valid integer value string to an int. Otherwise it will throw an exception. So make sure you pass a valid integer value to it. Sometimes the trailing space in the string causes exception. So call trim method on the input string to avoid that:

```
 int subjectid=Integer.parseInt(subject.trim());
```

Also make sure that subject is not null. So this seems better:

```
 String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
 int subjectid = 0;
 if(subject !=null && !subject.isEmpty())
     subjectid=Integer.parseInt(subject.trim());
```

Comment: ya i tried but it was showing that i can accept that answer after 6 min. Thats why its get late sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing up your data types, trying to convert `getParameter("subject")` to an Integer.

Perhaps you have a parameter named `"subject_id"`, and could this work?

```
 String subject_id_string=request.getParameter("subject_id");
 int subjectid=Integer.parseInt(subject_id_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
int subjectid = Integer.parseInt(subject.trim());
```

From the documentation

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.